# Can not find "locale.properties" file from PDF.js

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I use this plugin: [PDF.js](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js).

I am trying to solve the problems that show in console log.

Follow image:

[image]

[Here](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21AK-wYy1E6_vKfoo&cid=90C9FF791F5F2611&id=90C9FF791F5F2611%21960815&parId=90C9FF791F5F2611%21960814&action=locate) is a simple project ready, only download and run project you will see the same problem. I've tried everything and I can not solve a problem.

Follow html:

```
<div style="width: 800px; height: 500px;">
    <iframe width="800" height="500" id="iframePdfViewer" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" src="~/Scripts/pdfjs-dist/web/viewer.html"></iframe>
</div>
```

See another image that contains "locale.properties" file:

[image]

And I also get a lot of warnings from l10n.js. I downloaded it here: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ by clicking the "download" button.

Any solution ?

Answer (score 18):

Adding `.properties` MIME type configuration inside web.config file should work:

```
<configuration>
  <!-- other stuff -->

  <system.webServer>
     <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".properties" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
     </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If the project is already deployed in IIS (not IIS Express), go to site name => `MIME Types` => `Add`, and set `.properties` extension with `application/octet-stream` type as in provided image below:

[image: MIME Type Setting]

Here is the console log view with all `l10n.js` errors disappear:

[image: Console Result]

The reason behind usage of `application/octet-stream` is that the corresponding file should be treated as stream, even file contents are readable and stored in text format.

Reference: [l10n.js - locale.properties 404 (Not Found)](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/9643)

Answer (score 5):

If you are using .net core (2.1) try to add .properties as static file in your "public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)" method

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".properties"] = "application/octet-stream"; 

app.UseSpaStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
      ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Comment: Does it is same for .net core mvc 6.0?

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by Lukáš Janeček, If you are using .net core(3.1). try to add the following code to your public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

```
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();
provider.Mappings[".properties"] = "application/octet-stream";
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
{
     ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

Comment: This works in .net 6 also. Thanks!